# Problem with installing LibrePlan

Tags: apt, 18.04, ppa

I am trying to install LibrePlan on Ubuntu 18.04, the instructions say that I should run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreplan/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreplan
```

But on the first command i get this:

```
LibrePlan (aka NavalPlan) is a free software web application for     
project management. It is written in Java and licensed under 
AGPLlicense.
More info: https://launchpad.net/~libreplan/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.
Hit:1 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease  [88,7 kB]
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreplan/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
Get:4 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB] 
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreplan/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release             
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83,2 kB]    
Get:7 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [290 kB]
Get:8 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [262 kB]
Get:9 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [138 kB]
Get:10 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [27,5 kB]
Get:11 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [53,7 kB]
Get:12 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [161 kB]
Get:13 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [161 kB]
Get:14 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [152 kB]
Get:15 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [153 kB]
Get:16 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [265 kB]
Get:17 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2468 B]
Get:18 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5096 B]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [204 B]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5788 B]
Reading package lists... Done               
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreplan/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I see that the url http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreplan/ppa/ubuntu points to a repository containing "dists"  which is not containing bionic folder is that the problem? Simply the package for Ubuntu 18.04 is not ready (if I use the word package correctly) ?

In addition I've tried to add the key     `B4BE203D09B8AF1F528B8D1054CAAB19DE395C80` with `sudo apt-key add key.txt` but the following error occured `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.` The key is located at https://launchpad.net/~libreplan

Comment: libreplan has not been maintained since 15.04 (Vivid)  http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreplan/ppa/ubuntu/dists/  Best to probably contact Libreplan themselves about this:  http://www.libreplan.org/

Answer (score 0):

Got it working on both **Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04** by adding **some additional steps to the original guide**:

Install requirements:

```
apt-get install git-core maven openjdk-8-jdk postgresql postgresql-client python-docutils make gettext cutycapt
```

**Set default JDK**:

```
update-java-alternatives -s java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Connect to database:

```
su postgres -c psql
```

Use SQL sentences:

```
CREATE DATABASE libreplandev;
CREATE DATABASE libreplandevtest;
CREATE USER libreplan WITH PASSWORD 'libreplan';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE libreplandev TO libreplan;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE libreplandevtest TO libreplan;
```

Download source code:

```
git clone git://github.com/LibrePlan/libreplan.git
```

**Add missing dependency to the end of libreplan/libreplan-webapp/pom.xml**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.olap4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>olap4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Compile project **but skip tests**:

```
cd libreplan/
mvn -DskipTests clean install
```

Launch application:

```
cd libreplan-webapp/
mvn jetty:run
```

Go to http://localhost:8080/